# How to detect if protocol exists in ClojureScript object?

Tags: clojurescript

I have a series of ClojureScript objects, but only some of them implement a certain protocol. how can I detect if the protocol is extended on a particular object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `satisfies?` to check if the object extends the protocol.

```
(defprotocol p
  (go [_] nil))

(deftype t []
  p
  (go [this] true))

(satisfies? p (t.)) ;=> true
```